# How do I fix an Index Error in Numpy for use in a model for machine learning?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, probability

I was trying to predict the probability of a person to be using a certain drug. One of the vital predictions is showing an IndexError.

This is for a prediction. I've used this structure with no problems on different predictions with no problems.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.ensemble as skle
drug = pd.read_sas('C:/Users/hamee/Downloads/DUQ_I.xpt')
mod = skle.RandomForestClassifier()
fitmod = mod.fit(drug2[["DUQ200", "DUQ240", "DUQ250", "DUQ290", "DUQ330", "DUQ370"]], drug2["DUQ240"])
Pred = fitmod.predict_proba(drug2[["DUQ200", "DUQ240", "DUQ250", "DUQ290", "DUQ330", "DUQ370"]])
Brier = np.mean((Pred[:,1]-drug2["DUQ290"]**2))
```

### I expected an output of a decimal or a large number, The output was :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-90c24bde1c32> in <module>
----> 1 Brier = np.mean((Pred[:,1]-drug2["DUQ290"]**2))

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Comment: Right before that line (`Brier = ...`) print `Pred.shape`.  What the result?

Comment: What is the shape of `drug2["DUQ290"]`?? Try `Pred[:,0]-...`

Comment: Pred.shape = (539,1)

Comment: I just tried the "Pred[:,0], which worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything up to your `Pred` is working correctly

Your `Pred` is a one dimensional array, try `Pred.shape`, it should return a tuple of `(length, )`. Hence you only need to do

```
Brier = np.mean((Pred-drug2["DUQ290"]**2))
```

Update: since your `Pred.shape` is `(539, 1)`, it should be:

```
Brier = np.mean((Pred[:,0]-drug2["DUQ290"]**2))
```

as all list indices starts from `0`.

Comment: The data is not a one dimensional array, this is the output after this change:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-7ad092b78e4c> in <module>
----> 1 Brier = np.mean((Pred-drug2["DUQ290"]**2))

~\Anaconda3\
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: So what is `Pred.shape`?

Comment: Pred.shape = (539,1)

Comment: The correct way to address this would then be: `Pred[:, 0]`